# How to convert Tx_raw to Tx_ID/HASH

Tags: python, hash, transactions, bitcoin

I have a transaction details and i want to extract the transaction hash.

I am having a problem finding out a transaction hash/ID of this transaction. can any of you specify on which did my converting gone wrong. cause i really cant see it

```
<Tx version: 1
 <prevTxIn : 86395c6a5481bd70866f1537caa06bc0533e483cf8358a11081ab4fdd82de601 
 prev_index: 0, 
 script_sig: b'483045022100adaa0921ef15771abc9aeb959fce194b0283852bc336614ffc6deeebc19e21ee0220364135571d7899f3f9709a3e07f419dc62a7cb53eca65a85a3a1129a91d7d01c01210246607e02ba8f5dca52f54d09fce649ba80c711558ccaa0457487462faaf2301f',
 sequence: 4294967295 
> 
<TxOut: 2150152600 
 script_pub_key: b'76a914320a4a30144df4b885080e843e95bb4b3332a68f88ac'> 
,<TxOut: 849837400 
 script_pub_key: b'76a9143810d46cafb8e59d957f9fc47b9a9d22dc14807a88ac'> 
, 
locktime: 0>


def get_hash(raw):
return codecs.encode(double_sha256(raw), "hex_codec")
```

from that transaction i got this RAW transaction:

```
b'010000000101e62dd8fdb41a08118a35f83c483e53c06ba0ca37156f8670bd81546a5c3986000000006b483045022100adaa0921ef15771abc9aeb959fce194b0283852bc336614ffc6deeebc19e21ee0220364135571d7899f3f9709a3e07f419dc62a7cb53eca65a85a3a1129a91d7d01c01210246607e02ba8f5dca52f54d09fce649ba80c711558ccaa0457487462faaf2301fffffffff0298b92880000000001976a914320a4a30144df4b885080e843e95bb4b3332a68f88ac587da732000000001976a9143810d46cafb8e59d957f9fc47b9a9d22dc14807a88ac00000000'>
```

and when i do get_hash(raw):
i get:

```
ID:b'f799bc123ad2e961ed4347a83c933dc931b5d92cadf7c17c3a254b2378ebd036',
```

which is false because the actual transaction is here :
https://btc.com/202bf3d8baf05d63ab0e00f3874071a54846e02ea74e87efc6bccb89a491bd71#in_0

with an ID of `202bf3d8baf05d63ab0e00f3874071a54846e02ea74e87efc6bccb89a491bd71`

please if anyone can help me specify on which part of my process that i messed up i would really appereciate it!
thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Essentially, you cannot convert the hex string into a binary string via b'. That is, you're telling the double_hash function that `'AB1023'`, is already a binary string, when it's not. Instead, you must first convert the hex string into binary via some conversion function.

I like to use the binascii package for that. `binascii.unhexlify(raw)`

So your new function would look like:

```py
import binascii

def get_hash(raw):
    return codecs.encode(double_sha256(binascii.unhexlify(raw)), "hex_codec")
```

Hope this helped, or that you figured it out already.